# extract part of a filename python and insert into the MySQL DB

Tags: python, extract, filenames

Want to extract the filename from a directory and insert it into MySQL DB.

with glob.glob could easily extract the full path and filename from the particular directory. I only need the 1st part of the filename. The part I want to omit is fixed, but the part I want to keep may change as it depends on the time stamp.

part of the code is like this:

```
for name in glob.glob(r'/home/PROJ/result/*fileinfo.csv'):
    print (name)
    filename = os.path.basename(name)
    print(filename)

    filetail = str("_fileinfo.csv")
    print(filetail)
```

Print out shows as

```
/home/PROJ/result/Line01-200213_1625_fileinfo.csv
Line01-200213_1625_fileinfo.csv
_fileinfo.csv
/home/PROJ/result/Line01-200215_1619_fileinfo.csv
Line01-200215_1619_fileinfo.csv
_fileinfo.csv
```

I just want the 'lineNo-YYMMDD_hhmm' part as a filename. Omit the '_fileinfo.csv' part from the filename and store it in a file. Then insert in DB.

Comment: How far have you got in terms of mysql access, do you have a connection established and just need to preprocess the string and insert the records, for example?

Comment: In other module I could access DB and extract parameter from there to use. So accessing part should not be a problem I suppose. But haven't UPDATE or INSERT data through Python yet. That will be part-2 of this work. Stuck her due to lack of exp.

Comment: Do the filenames always end with `fileinfo.csv`?

Comment: Yes. there are other files also in that directory with same 'fileHeader'. But right now only dealing with this file type (end of _fileinfo.csv). If needed can use the same way to extract the fileHeader from other files I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting the part you want, you can strip out the filenames:

```
for name in glob.glob(r'/home/PROJ/result/*fileinfo.csv'):
    file_prefix = os.path.basename(name)[:-(len('fileinfo.csv')+1)]
    print(file_prefix)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Could you pl explain it simply? The last part actually. [:-(len('fileinfo.csv')+1)]

Comment: I think I got it.